# Save only one plot from tsdiag

Tags: r, arima

I would like to retrieve and save to file only one plot out three from `tsdiag` function.

[image]

How can I achieve that? I've been trying to use additional parameter `which` but the plotting function is still returning the whole diagnosis.

```r
tsdiag(arima_model, which = 1)  # does not work
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation of `stats` either. It's quite easy to reproduce these plots manually but it would be great to get only one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider `tsdiag.Sarima()` from package `sarima` (https://cran.r-project.org/package=sarima), which provides the requested and further functionality, see https://geobosh.github.io/sarima/reference/tsdiag.Sarima.html. Another feature of `tsdiag.Sarima()` is that it uses the correct degrees of freedom to calculate p-values, which is another reason to use it.  `tsdiag.Sarima()` offers also some alternative tests, see its help page or the link above.

For example, fit an ARIMA model to builtin `AirPassengers` data:

```
ap.arima <- arima(log(AirPassengers), order = c(0,1,1), seasonal = c(0,1,1))
```

This shows a graph similar to the default `tsdiag` one but with the d.f. as required by for the Ljung-Box test:

```
tsdiag.Sarima(ap.arima)
```

This shows also the Li-McLeod test (the residuals are dropped here):

```
tsdiag.Sarima(ap.arima, plot = 2:4)
```

Argument `layout` can be used to define a different layout of the plots, see `?layout` for details. In the simplest case, it is a matrix with 1 column.
This shows the autocorrelations and the LB p-values:

```
tsdiag.Sarima(ap.arima, plot = 2:3, layout = list(matrix(1:2, nrow = 2)))
```

`plot` can specify non-contiguous plots, of course.
This shows the autocorrelations and the partial autocorrelations of the residuals

```
tsdiag.Sarima(ap.arima, plot = c(2,6), layout = list(matrix(1:2, nrow = 2)))
```

If argument `plot` specifies more plots than the layout can accommodate, you will get a menu to choose the desired plots:

```
tsdiag.Sarima(ap.arima, plot = 1:6, layout = list(matrix(1:2, nrow = 2)))
```

presents something like:

```
Select a plot number or 0 to exit 

1: residuals
2: acf of residuals
3: p values for Ljung-Box statistic
4: p values for Li-McLeod statistic
5: p values for Box-Pierce statistic
6: pacf of residuals

Selection:
```

`layout` allows you to allocate different amount of space to the plots, as well. This allocates 2/(1+2+2) of the vertical space (40%) to each of the second and third plot, and only 20% to the first (the standardised residuals):

```
tsdiag.Sarima(ap.arima, plot = c(1,2,6), 
    layout = list(matrix(1:3, nrow = 3),
    heights = c(1,2,2)))
```

The above works also for objects obtained from `auto.arima`. This modification of the example from the previous answer uses `tsdiag.Sarima`:

```
library("forecast")   # contains auto.arima
data(manaus, package = "boot")

m <- auto.arima(manaus)

tsdiag.Sarima(m)             # all plots
tsdiag.Sarima(m, plot = 2, layout = list(1))    # only 2nd
tsdiag.Sarima(m, plot = 2:3, layout = list(matrix(1:2, nrow = 2))) # plot 2 & 3
```

Comment: I think I am going to accept this answer instead of the previous one – I don't have to redefine the library code with minor modifications and this one has more functionalities

Answer (score 1):

**R** is open source, so one can have a look in the sources and check if it is possible to create an own user-modified  function.

The `tsdiag`function is found in package **stats**, source file `ama0.R`. Here a hacked version that supports a `which`-argument:

```r
## modified from R package stats, file `ama0.R`
tsdiag.Arima <- tsdiag.arima0 <- function(object, gof.lag = 10, which = 1L:3L, ...) {
  ## plot standardized residuals, acf of residuals, Ljung-Box p-values
  oldpar <- par(mfrow = c(length(which), 1))
  on.exit(par(oldpar))
  rs <- object$residuals
  if (1L %in% which) {
    stdres <- rs/sqrt(object$sigma2)
    plot(stdres, type = "h", main = "Standardized Residuals", ylab = "")
    abline(h = 0)
  }
  if (2L %in% which) {
    acf(object$residuals, plot = TRUE, main = "ACF of Residuals",
        na.action = na.pass)
  }
  if (3L %in% which) {
    nlag <- gof.lag
    pval <- numeric(nlag)
    for(i in 1L:nlag) pval[i] <- Box.test(rs, i, type="Ljung-Box")$p.value
    plot(1L:nlag, pval, xlab = "lag", ylab = "p value", ylim = c(0,1),
         main = "p values for Ljung-Box statistic")
    abline(h = 0.05, lty = 2, col = "blue")
  }
}
```

Now we can test it:

```r
library("forecast")   # contains auto.arima
library("boot")       # contains manaus data set

m <- auto.arima(manaus)

tsdiag(m)             # all plots
tsdiag(m, which=1)    # only 2nd
tsdiag(m, which=2:3)  # plot 2 and 3
```

Comment: This is perfect, especially using something like `c(1, 3)`. Thanks!